# Python binary to decimal converter (without using built-ins)

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, number-systems

Any ideas how I could improve this? I already know that there is no checking for anything other than a `1`, so you can enter a `2` or an `a` or a `b` and it will be interpreted as a `0`, not interfering with the program's functionality. What I would like to know is if anyone has any suggestions for improving the logic.

```
def main():

  #Input
  binary = input("Enter a line of binary: ")

  #Reverses input
  toCalc = binary[::-1]

  #Finds length of input
  binLen = len(binary)

  #Variables
  total = 0
  exp = 0 #Exponent

  #loop while current character place is less than input length
  while exp < binLen:
    if toCalc[exp] == "1": #If current char is a '1', add 2^exp to the total
        total += 2 ** int(exp)
    exp += 1
  print (total)
  main()


main()
```

[Here](https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/4c5f27569e) is a link to a working version of the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This algorithm could pretty easily be converted to a one-liner.  Let's walk through the logic:

1. You want to work over each element of a string.  You can just iterate over the string, rather than keeping track of an index.
2. You also need the index of that element, so you can use `enumerate` to get both.
3. You want to apply a mathematical operation if and only if the integer is not `0`.  This can be done using `int(val)`, which converts the value to the number it represents.
4. You want to add all the values at the end.  This can be done with `sum`.

To get error checking, you can convert the string to a `set`, and make sure the `set` is equal to a set with only `0` and `1` in it.

Also, you probably want the `input` handling in a `while` loop to avoid the recursion, which will fill up your memory, and then have a separate function to handle the actual conversion.

Also, I would only run `main` if the code is run as a script.

And keep in mind python has a [built-in way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928256/3604159) to do binary to decimal conversion: `int(binstr, 2)`, which can be used to test your implementation at the very least.

So here is how I would implement it:

```
def bin2int(binstr):
    if set(binstr) != {'0', '1'}:
        raise ValueError('String is not binary: "%s"' % binstr)

    return sum(int(x)*2**i for i, x in enumerate(a[::-1]))


def main():
    while True:
        binary = input("Enter a line of binary, enter 'q' to quit: ")

        if binary.lower() == 'q':
            break

        try:
            print(bin2int(binary))
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```